# Idiomatic way to use multiple references shared by simple structs

Tags: rust, mutable, borrow-checker

I want to have a
set of functions to operate on a given structure. Two CPUs need to access
one single mutable memory.
From what I've read,  I need `Rc<RefCell<_>>`.
This is akin to the problem of the representing a tree
but it is simpler since my structs have relationships defined at compile time and don't need to be generic.

The code below works, but I wonder if it is idiomatic.
Coming from OOP background, I find it quite problematic:

1. Although the `memory` field is present in the `Cpu` struct, I have to
   apply a `borrow_mut()` on it each time I need to access it in the
   `impl`. Is this because Rust wants me to avoid two
   simultaneous mutable references?
2. I have to pass the `mem` parameter to the `do_stuff`
   function. If I have dozens of nested functions I'll have to pass
   that parameter on each call. Is it possible to avoid that?
3. If I pass that parameter around, then it'd be just as simple
   to *not have* the memory field in the `Cpu` struct, and just passing
   `mut &Memory` references around instead which questions the need for the
   `Rc<RefCell<Memory>>` construct...

Code sample:

```
use std::cell::{RefCell, RefMut};
use std::rc::Rc;

struct Cpu {
    memory: Rc<RefCell<Memory>>
}

impl Cpu {
    fn new(m : Rc<RefCell<Memory>>) -> Cpu {
        Cpu { memory: m } }

    fn run(&mut self) {
       self.do_stuff(self.memory.borrow_mut());
       // Show repetition of borrow_mut (point 1)
       self.do_stuff(self.memory.borrow_mut()); 
    }

    // Show the need for mem parameter (point 2)
    fn do_stuff(&self, mut mem: RefMut<Memory>) { 
       let i = mem.load(4) + 10;
       mem.set(4, i);
    }
}

struct Memory { pub mem: [u8; 5] }
impl Memory {
    fn new() -> Memory { Memory { mem: [0 as u8; 5] } }
    fn load( &self, ndx : usize) -> u8 { self.mem[ndx] }
    fn set( &mut self, ndx : usize, val: u8) { self.mem[ndx] = val }
}
    
fn main() {
    let memory: Rc<RefCell<_>> = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Memory::new()));
    let mut cpu1 = Cpu::new(memory.clone());
    let mut cpu2 = Cpu::new(memory.clone());
    cpu1.run();
    cpu2.run();
    println!("{}",memory.borrow().mem[4]);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have to apply a `borrow_mut()` on it each time I need to access it in the `impl`. Is this because Rust wants me to avoid two simultaneous mutable references?

Yes. There's a tidy analogy with physical hardware, here: your two processors must have some mechanism to avoid conflicts resulting from accessing the memory bus at the same time. In this analogy, using `RefCell` is a bus arbiter*: it sees the requests and grants or denies them to ensure there's only one access at a time. The alternative you have identified, passing an `&mut Memory` to each call, is like there being a single clock which cycles through giving non-overlapping time-slices of the memory access to each CPU.

The second option is generally considered better and more idiomatic Rust, *when it is practical.* It is statically checked, avoiding the overhead of updating the borrow flags inside a `RefCell`. Its main disadvantage is that it requires the caller to pass in the right `&mut` reference — which is not a problem in straightforward and tightly-coupled situations like yours.

A third option, in this situation where you have a simple integer array, would be to simulate something closer to the way memory works from the perspective of the real CPU: store your memory as `[Cell<u8>; 5]` or `[AtomicU8; 5]`, so that each addressable location is allowed to be independently modified *at any time*, even if you have a non-exclusive `&` reference to it rather than `&mut`. This allows more complex code structures than passing around `&mut Memory`, but does not require explicit borrowing/locking of the *entire* memory like using a `RefCell` does. It offers you the *least static or dynamic checking* against conflicting mutations, but it might be appropriate if the operations you intend to implement are not well aligned with that checking.

---

* I'm not a CPU hardware expert and may not be using the exact right terms.

Comment: Interesting answer. In your second option, can I conclude that if I have a hundred of "do_stuff" functions, possibly calling eachother to achieve complex operations on memory, I'll most likely have to pass `&mut mem` references to each functions, from one to the other (so a rather "functional" approach) ? That's the scenario I try to avoid although I feel rust pushes towards it for good reasons.

Comment: @wiz21 You're always going to be passing *something* to each function, whether it is `&mut Memory`, `&Memory`, `&mut self` inside of `impl Memory`, or some struct containing such a reference (as `Cpu` did in your original code). (Unless you make the memory a global variable, which is probably not a good idea.)

Answer (score 0):

> 2. I have to pass the mem parameter to the do_stuff function. If I have dozens of nested functions I'll have to pass that parameter on each call. Is it possible to avoid that?

You can avoid that by introducing a type that both holds the mutable reference to the memory and defines the behavior:

```
struct CpuMem<'a> {
    mem: &'a mut Memory,
}

impl CpuMem<'_> {
    fn do_stuff(&mut self) {
        // can call other functions on self without passing an explicit `mem`
        let i = self.mem.load(4) + 10;
        self.mem.set(4, i);
    }
}
```

Your `Cpu` can define a utility function that obtains the memory:

```
fn mem(mem: &mut Memory) -> CpuMem {
    CpuMem { mem }
}
```

after which `run()` can look like this:

```
fn run(&mut self) {
    let mut borrow = self.memory.borrow_mut();
    let mut mem = Self::mem(borrow.deref_mut());
    mem.do_stuff();
    mem.do_stuff();
}
```

If `do_stuff()` and other need to access some fields from `Cpu`, you can put references to those other things in `CpuMem` as well. You can also put a reference to the Cpu itself there, but then you calling a function that borrows memory, such as `run()`, will simply panic at run-time.